# Error messages popping up in terminal, may be related to Chromium, may be related to Anaconda

Tags: command-line, chromium

This is my first question so be critical. Be very critical.

Since yesterday I have had error messages popping up in my terminal but they are unrelated to my actions in terminal but with what little connections I've found in my searching it *seems* to be related to Chromium and/or Anaconda.

The only way I have been able to keep the error messages coming is having Chromium open and have my Anaconda virtualenv activated. There have been no problems with either of these applications. Here are some of the error messages:

```
[7025:7025:0319/184720.273968:ERROR:sync_control_vsync_provider.cc(62)] glXGetSyncValuesOML should not return TRUE with a media stream counter of 0.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[6955:6991:0319/204342.152673:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(381)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[6955:6991:0320/063651.385576:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(381)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[6955:6955:0320/063835.487110:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(208)] Invalid first_meaningful_paint (unset) for time_to_interactive 2.118 s
```

(above from this morning)

```
[6955:6955:0319/181306.499583:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(208)] Invalid first_meaningful_paint (unset) for time_to_interactive 1.183 s
[6955:6955:0319/181337.676909:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(208)] Invalid first_meaningful_paint (unset) for time_to_interactive 1.183 s
[6955:6955:0319/181340.533990:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(208)] Invalid first_meaningful_paint (unset) for time_to_interactive 1.183 s
```

They were even happening inside the Python interactive shell

```
>>> [6955:6955:0319/180415.819659:ERROR:media_internals.cc(102)] Cannot get RenderProcessHost

>>> [6955:6955:0319/181105.025510:ERROR:media_internals.cc(102)] Cannot get RenderProcessHost

>>> [6955:6955:0319/180415.819659:ERROR:media_internals.cc(102)] Cannot get RenderProcessHost[6955:6955:0319/181231.589079:ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(208)] Invalid first_meaningful_paint (unset) for time_to_interactive 1.183 s
```

#### What I do know

- I know that `.cc` files are C++ files but that's the extent of my knowledge. I'm just a fledgling programmer and Linux user though.
- Chromium: Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)
- conda 4.4.11

Most questions asked on this are loosely related and the errors are found in the browser. Even if you can point me in the right direction that would be great, or have seen this somewhere before.

Thank you!

Comment: I didn't have anymore issues after quitting the virtual environment and restarting my computer. I have also downloaded Chrome since.